# How to print RSA* as string in C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, rsa

How to properly print RSA* as string in C++?

I am using `OpenSSL`. It doesn't seem to have a `.c_str()` method, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RSA_print_fp(stdout, x, 0);
```

http://linux.die.net/man/3/rsa_print_fp

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you please explain in detail more about this. I don't have enough knowledge about this.

Comment: As documentation says, this function writes string representation of given `RSA*` object `x` to given `FILE*` stream. `stdout` has type `FILE*` and represents your console. When you write to this "file", data is displayed in program standard output.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <memory>
using std::unique_ptr;

#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>  

#include <cassert>
#define ASSERT assert

using BN_ptr = std::unique_ptr<BIGNUM, decltype(&::BN_free)>;
using RSA_ptr = std::unique_ptr<RSA, decltype(&::RSA_free)>;
using BIO_MEM_ptr = std::unique_ptr<BIO, decltype(&::BIO_free)>;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int rc;

    RSA_ptr rsa(RSA_new(), ::RSA_free);
    BN_ptr bn(BN_new(), ::BN_free);
    BIO_MEM_ptr bio(BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()), ::BIO_free);

    rc = BN_set_word(bn.get(), RSA_F4);
    ASSERT(rc == 1);

    rc = RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa.get(), 2048, bn.get(), NULL);
    ASSERT(rc == 1);

    rc = RSA_print(bio.get(), rsa.get(), 0);
    ASSERT(rc == 1);

    BUF_MEM* mem = NULL;
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio.get(), &mem);
    ASSERT(mem != NULL);

    string s;
    if(mem->data && mem->length)
        s.assign(mem->data, mem->length);

    if(s.length())
        cout << s << endl;
    else
        cout << "Failed to retrieve key" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

A typical run:

```
$ ./test-openssl.exe
Private-Key: (1024 bit)
modulus:
    00:9e:44:ab:26:da:2d:42:3f:ea:06:1f:3b:80:22:
    39:0f:89:ee:38:ba:f9:49:a6:7d:69:be:f7:b8:43:
    30:db:7b:32:82:09:89:c4:84:43:af:75:33:22:40:
    07:ad:43:c8:56:54:f3:c5:6e:a5:bc:a6:b2:83:49:
    a4:07:8e:d3:b8:a1:5b:c9:55:04:0a:01:73:12:85:
    93:ef:20:0b:29:2e:a8:2d:4f:4a:1d:ad:31:b8:81:
    dd:57:49:3c:d1:57:71:29:c3:34:1c:cf:ba:31:86:
    cb:d6:d7:92:b9:3c:84:ca:2e:f6:fa:85:0a:86:e4:
    b1:e0:1e:00:86:d9:c6:14:37
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    5e:1d:7f:99:af:0c:52:e5:27:09:54:f1:51:15:08:
    d1:90:b8:34:cc:1b:0a:0d:13:6f:1a:bc:bc:ba:58:
    07:6c:8f:70:7c:b3:8c:45:0a:ea:ff:ca:d4:87:37:
    09:75:d1:60:65:4c:41:0f:b7:47:23:e9:eb:e0:92:
    c6:5b:cc:d2:82:d5:f3:42:75:d4:88:95:35:20:62:
    f9:9a:18:df:6b:5b:ff:6c:97:11:63:d6:24:2c:86:
    bb:be:c1:ed:a3:87:8e:78:70:7a:c8:fc:73:9c:53:
    70:eb:ff:06:b9:91:be:81:56:a5:25:71:d3:54:09:
    04:ea:8d:1e:8e:48:eb:c1
prime1:
    00:cc:25:66:b7:dc:66:64:eb:5c:f2:15:9f:7b:66:
    c0:9e:8d:51:63:e0:8b:15:73:64:54:d2:62:35:a6:
    14:29:20:ba:92:3e:dc:d4:32:6a:c6:ba:45:56:94:
    3e:77:e1:ab:e0:60:cf:12:2b:09:1f:45:0e:2c:b2:
    49:1e:85:66:ef
prime2:
    00:c6:78:0f:44:19:cc:74:22:32:58:d1:ee:a7:6f:
    fa:b4:57:a4:4a:7c:7a:52:53:c8:52:48:34:05:b4:
    59:3f:18:a3:88:17:fd:ae:2e:54:d7:83:2c:a9:bf:
    52:7b:f4:e9:af:02:61:99:fa:35:4a:b0:e4:a0:8c:
    5f:f8:d8:67:39
exponent1:
    00:a3:41:7d:c5:a7:72:13:5e:cd:b3:a3:6b:28:ca:
    61:5b:ea:73:9e:45:e1:b4:43:d5:86:a7:c0:76:5a:
    dc:60:8f:95:e4:82:75:23:15:36:a2:ba:2f:dd:2f:
    2c:4d:be:a1:2f:0c:fc:4b:f1:32:98:59:27:1e:c3:
    6d:0a:05:70:ed
exponent2:
    00:97:d5:de:08:01:9c:b2:f4:3e:84:49:07:45:bd:
    9b:95:40:bf:85:e4:b9:48:26:a4:c8:9e:48:7e:5c:
    bd:32:52:4d:39:9e:f1:0a:c2:93:51:d5:1e:e4:36:
    64:8a:44:92:4a:bb:8d:a3:d9:11:d0:34:88:94:73:
    10:31:36:8d:b1
coefficient:
    1d:97:1c:37:72:66:87:6f:a8:10:5d:bf:02:31:3d:
    69:bb:a8:13:78:cb:20:d7:70:ee:f9:ba:1e:a9:e1:
    ca:5b:db:a8:12:64:39:32:4f:0b:b8:0e:0f:fc:2c:
    ec:89:25:06:bf:84:d7:94:e5:18:bd:80:f4:74:ba:
    5e:0a:4c:24
```

---

If you don't like that output, you can access the `RSA` members directly. For example:

```
// RSA object 'owns' the BIGNUM. Don't destroy it.
BIGNUM* n = rsa.get()->n;
BIGNUM* e = rsa.get()->e;
BIGNUM* d = rsa.get()->d;

string s;

BIO_reset(bio.get());
mem = NULL;

rc = BN_print(bio.get(), n);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio.get(), &mem);
if(mem && mem->data && mem->length)
    s.assign(mem->data, mem->length);

if(s.length())
    cout << "Modulus: " << endl << s << endl;
else
    cout << "Failed to retrieve modulus" << endl;

BIO_reset(bio.get());
mem = NULL;

rc = BN_print(bio.get(), e);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio.get(), &mem);
if(mem && mem->data && mem->length)
    s.assign(mem->data, mem->length);

if(s.length())
    cout << "Public exponent: " << endl << s << endl;
else
    cout << "Failed to retrieve public exponent" << endl;

BIO_reset(bio.get());
mem = NULL;

rc = BN_print(bio.get(), d);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio.get(), &mem);
if(mem && mem->data && mem->length)
    s.assign(mem->data, mem->length);

if(s.length())
    cout << "Private exponent: " << endl << s << endl;
else
    cout << "Failed to retrieve private exponent" << endl;
```

Output will be similar to:

```
Modulus: 
E00226E63C7BE6A23990592F3F861393B1F563D7CF57699619E6ED558EFA6D64C326203825E163EF
28B7B3608C68B8A9F1A5952FA8E4C42A4F6066BE6D1502D20894577C91DB94F6F596891DCF9532E2
19FBAEA1201215E014DEE8A270BEABDFC7D00860BF3C08A26707CADAECCF9A2229984C23F198691E
B59D26D4AC8460BD
Public exponent: 
10001
Private exponent: 
3D3E99600D5D5ABB33BDD184677BC2D278AF3CB2FE4F49E0EE08030F875DD496DDFC08871164442C
591790856F1E1A8EEC30774F667FD55A34058951BB052995BC24A80AAA547E1764FB33500007A743
C9B41F376F655EB8BDD729172F8592886C299994565F9F72A0235CBB22AA33BD1A2D20AF07DCBAC5
6DB22E4DCBC4DCC1
```

---

If you like the formatting of the first example (the octets separated with a colon), then take a look at `ASN1_bn_print`. You can use it to print `RSA` members in turn. `RSA_print` and `RSA_print_fp` internally calls `ASN1_bn_print`. There's an example of it at [OpenSSL command in c to get Modulus of a public Key in the RSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176439/openssl-command-in-c-to-get-modulus-of-a-public-key-in-the-rsa).

```
BIGNUM* n = rsa.get()->n;

int req = BN_num_bytes(n) + 4;
unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(req);

rc = ASN1_bn_print(bio.get(), "Modulus:", n, ptr, 0);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio.get(), &mem);
if(mem && mem->data && mem->length)
    s.assign(mem->data, mem->length);

if(s.length())
    cout << s << endl;
else
    cout << "Failed to retrieve modulus" << endl;
```

It will produce output similar to:

```
Modulus:
    00:bf:49:fa:f2:30:21:42:de:91:60:f3:02:37:87:
    86:f4:eb:85:2c:95:86:42:69:6f:bc:cf:3f:27:9e:
    17:b6:44:06:5f:e7:ea:9f:e8:38:a7:5a:d5:da:9f:
    4b:26:df:78:15:d7:df:22:c0:16:12:77:f9:18:aa:
    85:01:21:3a:b0:ae:39:b8:07:cd:d4:2c:a3:0b:1c:
    df:be:09:03:09:76:5f:a1:1e:c0:00:8e:bf:b2:40:
    e2:3c:eb:d1:85:6f:7a:ab:35:c3:3a:c4:23:db:39:
    0c:d0:2b:39:b3:a5:a5:08:a2:e4:00:d5:0b:b0:87:
    62:ae:7c:a4:6c:e6:1c:d6:c9
```

---

You can also use `BN_bn2dec` and friends. For example:

```
BIGNUM* n = rsa.get()->n;
cout << "BN_bn2dec:" << endl;
cout << BN_bn2dec(n) << endl;
```

It will produce:

```
BN_bn2dec: 
12243739000135209335165415265342326792394455644180015057748915050940947919482400
64106225312022889083399949792870649447719809295883754268473265926413766309145047
08000254475023744104439182803717332048247971986885955229841406443364223719542912
385690146029374797423322891147172613041161904860242946608474463378207
```