# How to print the content of an OpenSSL RSA key

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

I'd like to print the content of an RSA key created using OpenSSL and accessed by means of the pointer

```
RSA * rsa;
```

Now, I've tried to use the RSA_print and BIO_read functions as follows:

```
BIO * keybio ;
RSA_print(keybio, rsa, 0);
char buffer [1024];
std::string res = "";
while (BIO_read (keybio, buffer, 1023) > 0)
{
    std::cout << buffer;
}
```

but I get a *segmentation fault* at the very first execution of the BIO_read (sixth line). Can someone spot the error?

Comment: Um does `BIO * keybio = malloc(sizeof(Bio));` help? I don't think `RSA_print()` allocates memory for `keybio`, and you are writing over an unallocated memory space. If it does I'll make it an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly print RSA\* as string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451936/how-to-properly-print-rsa-as-string-in-c)

Comment: Use `RSA_print` or `RSA_print_fp`. See the docs at [`RSA_print(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_print.html). Allow the key to be written to the `BIO`, and then read the data from the `BIO` to a `string`.

Comment: Don't waste effort in trying to make that loop work. `std::cout << buffer` is broken because `buffer` is not `NULL` terminated. Use `BIO_get_mem_ptr` to access the raw memory from the `BIO`.

Comment: "... I get a segmentation fault at the very first execution of the BIO_read" - the `BIO` does not appear to be initialized. You seem to be missing a `BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())`.

Comment: @gosbi - Please provide an answer in an answer block. Readers know to look in answer blocks for answers. Its OK if your answer your own question. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) on Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are writing over unallocated memory. I don't think `RSA_print()` allocates memory for `BIO`, so you are passing an uninitialized pointer to it.

EDIT: As @jww pointed out in the comment, the `BIO` object should be instantiated with a set of dedicated options. I edited the answer accordingly. I also changed the buffer size passed to `1024`.

Allocate space:

```
BIO * keybio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
RSA_print(keybio, rsa, 0);
char buffer [1024];
std::string res = "";
while (BIO_read (keybio, buffer, 1024) > 0)
{
    std::cout << buffer;
}
BIO_free(keybio); //appropriate free "method"
```

[`BIO_s_mem()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_mem.html) creates a memory `BIO` method function. And [`BIO_new()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_new.html) creates and initializes the object itself, using the supplied method.

Also please note that this code is `c`-style. There is a nice way of wrapping pure pointer into `c++` smart pointers, shown here: [How to properly print RSA* as string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451936/how-to-properly-print-rsa-as-string-in-c).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you meant `sizeof(BIO)`.

Anyway, both solutions compile but none of them solved the issue. I still have segmentation fault.

On the other hand, I think you are right about the dimension of the buffer.

Comment: You are right. It should be `BIO` of course. Does the `segfault` occur on the same line? I do not really see any other reason for it to fail like this. I would also suggest checking `RSA_print` result for error. However, even if it does fail, I don't think a subsequent call to `BIO_read` should segfault. It is worth of checking though.

Comment: I believe you need `BIO* keybio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());`. Its not clear to me where any initialization is occurring. At minimum: `BIO keybio = *BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());`

Comment: @jww I'll update my answer as soon as this is confirmed. Or you can write your own, and I will delete mine as incorrect then. I left it as a hint in case someone else would like to try it. Since there is no other answers I think it is not that offending as of yet.

Comment: @jww Thanks for link. Care to write your own answer, or want me to edit and get credited for your research work =) ?